# Physical-keyboard driven app launcher?

Tags: keyboard

On most operating systems, there's a keyboard shortcut to trigger a keyboard-driven app-launcher.

For example:

- On Windows: <kbd>Super</kbd> and start typing.
- On OSX: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and start typing.
- Linux: it varies, but same as OSX on Elementary OS.

Is there an equivalent launcher available for Android where I can push a key combo and start typing to find the app I'd like to launch?

Answer (score 1):

On the stock Google launcher, if you simply start typing, it'll search for the thing you typed for, both online and in local apps. You can cycle through the matches with the arrow keys, and launch one with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: That's awesome, but is there something that will do this no matter what app I'm in? That's kind of what I'm looking for. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pretty cool, but only useful for the last 6 apps.

Comment: Pressing the home key goes to the launcher from any app.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "alt-d" from the home screen when to the application launcher (though I needed to press some keys to get to the search box).

This was documented in the key-list that you could pop up with windows-/.